# How to get a value from Dataset and store it in a Scala value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
scala> avgsessiontime.show()
+-----------------+
|              avg|
+-----------------+
|2.073455735838315|
+-----------------+
```

I need to store the value 2.073455735838315 in a variable. I tried using

```
avgsessiontime.collect
```

but that starts giving me **Task not serializable exceptions**. So to avoid that I started using foreachPrtition. But I dont know how to extract the value 2.073455735838315 in an array variable.

```
scala> avgsessiontime.foreachPartition(x => x.foreach(println))
[2.073455735838315]
```

But when I do this:

```
avgsessiontime.foreachPartition(x => for (name <- x) name.get(0))
```

I get a blank/empty result. Even the length returns empty.

```
avgsessiontime.foreachPartition(x => for (name <- x) name.length)
```

I know name is of type org.apache.spark.sql.Row then it should return both those results.

Comment: _"but that starts giving me Task not serializable exceptions."_ <-- fix the real issue not introduce new ones (!) Can you paste the exception + the code? What's Spark version?

Answer (score 3):

You might need:

```
avgsessiontime.first.getDouble(0)
```

Here use `first` to extract the `Row` object, and `.getDouble(0)` to extract value from the `Row` object.

---

```
val df = Seq(2.0743).toDF("avg")

df.show
+------+
|   avg|
+------+
|2.0743|
+------+

df.first.getDouble(0)
// res6: Double = 2.0743
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that. I got "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable". I think first(), take(), collect() all work in the same way. Also I am running this is spark shell.

Comment: This works for me. You may try to restart your spark-shell, or make sure you don't have multiple spark shells open.

Comment: I ran my code separately (not as an app) and what you suggested worked. In fact even collect() worked. But as app it did not. I just added Object Match extends Serializable and it worked just fine ! adding "extends Serializable" was the key I guess.

Comment: If you find the solution to your problem, you may add it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val df = spark.range(10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> df.show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+
scala> val variable = df.select("id").as[Long].collect
variable: Array[Long] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Same way you can extract values of any type i.e double,string. You just need to give data type while selecting values from df.

Answer (score 1):

`rdd` and `dataframes/datasets` are distributed in nature, and `foreach` and `foreachPartition` are executed on *executor*s, transforming `dataframe` or `rdd` on executors itself without returning anything. So if you want to return the variable to the *driver* node then you will have to use `collect`.

Supposing you have a `dataframe` as

```
+-----------------+
|avg              |
+-----------------+
|2.073455735838315|
|2.073455735838316|
+-----------------+
```

doing the following will print all the values, which you can store in a variable too

```
avgsessiontime.rdd.collect().foreach(x => println(x(0)))
```

it will print

```
2.073455735838315
2.073455735838316
```

Now if you want only the first one then you can do

```
avgsessiontime.rdd.collect()(0)(0)
```

which will give you

```
2.073455735838315
```

I hope the answer is helpful